# How to convert points in ASCII to Bytes-based format

Tags: byte, points, point-clouds

**I have points in the format:**

0 1 0

1 1 2

1 0 1

**I need to translate them to:**

### HEADER

4 bytes, Number of points (N)
12 bytes, Bounding box minimum, float vec3
12 bytes, Bounding box maximum, float vec3

### DATA

N * ushort vec3 = Each point is a 3D vector with fixed-point normalized components. 
e.g. x stored ushort = x world * 65535.0f / (bound max x - bound min x)

I tried to use CloudCompare to export it in .ply format, but hex values didn't seem to match ASCII values.

This is needed for gvdb library described here:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1031640/gvdb-voxels/any-instruction-to-the-point-cloud-dat-format-in-gpointcloud-sample-/

Any ideas really appreciated.